# Keyboard shortcut to open context menu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

Does OS X have a Windows <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> equivalent? I need a keyboard shortcut to open the context menu without a mouse.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/how-do-i-open-the-context-menu-from-a-mac-keyboard?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, you have two options.

## Mouse Keys

When using Mouse Keys, you can use the keyboard to move the cursor. If you have a numerical keypad, the numbers around 5 are used to move it and 5 is used to click. Without a keypad, it's mapped to the nine keys surrounding I (789/UIO/JKL).

Just like with a mouse or trackpad, you can hold <kbd>⌃ control</kbd> while pressing <kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the context menu.

You can turn on Mouse Keys in System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad, or enable the press-<kbd>shift</kbd>-five-times toggle shortcut, or press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to bring up a window of Accessibility toggles, including Mouse Keys. This is important to know, as Mouse Keys makes typing impossible, at least without a number pad.

[image: Accessibility preferences]

## Third party utility

There are many applications that let you customize keyboard shortcuts, etc. There's [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/) (free), or [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) ($36), or several others. Any of these should let you create a shortcut to “right-click”.

[image: BetterTouchTool]

Comment: nice answer, cool utilities. wish apple would build in the shortcut natively ...