# Map the application key to right-click at caret position using Karabiner-Elements

Tags: keyboard, mouse, keybindings, karabiner

To map the application key to right-click using Karabiner-Elements one can use:

```
"simple_modifications": [
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "application"
        },
        "to": {
            "pointing_button": "button2"
        }
    },
```

However, this will perform a right-click at the position of the mouse pointer. I want it to move the pointer to the position of the caret and then perform the right-click.
Presumably, to do this I need to use `"complex_modifications"` `rule`.
My main problem is I don't know how to change the mouse pointer position to the caret position.
Using AutoHotkey there's an answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206243/moving-the-mouse-pointer-to-the-cursor
I can't say I really understand the answer there but anyway I'm looking to do this with Karabiner-Elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to remap to <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f10</kbd> instead, for example:

```json
"from": {
    "key_code": "right_option"
},
"to": [
    {
        "key_code": "f10",
        "modifiers": [
            "left_shift"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, ⇧f10 works only with some programs, like Office but not with a lot of others that I use. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/how-do-i-open-the-context-menu-from-a-mac-keyboard